# maven build error on java

Tags: java, maven

when i try to build the maven i got the following error how can i rectify this error.Here my code is

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Gooru
[INFO] gooru-core
[INFO] Gooru Cassandra Core
[INFO] Gooru API
[INFO] gooru-mail
[INFO] Gooru Application - Rest V2 WAR(Spring MVC)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Gooru 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Gooru ............................................. FAILURE [0.005s]
[INFO] gooru-core ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Gooru Cassandra Core .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Gooru API ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] gooru-mail ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Gooru Application - Rest V2 WAR(Spring MVC) ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.581s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 12 17:52:58 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/149M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Dmaven.test.skip=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Comment: Put a `-` in front of Dmaven.test.skip=true.

Comment: please post the full command you are using before you get the error, and your missing - before the D so its -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: How did you try to build? Right-click, run as.. Maven build?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `-` character.
Do `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`.

When defining properties in the command line, the correct command syntax is `-D` plus the property name, you can check more info about it [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)